# How to stop AWS ElasticBeanstalk from creating an S3 Bucket or inserting into it?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It created an S3 bucket. If I delete it, it just creates a new one. How can I set it to not create a bucket or to stop write permissions from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prevent AWS Elastic Beanstalk from creating S3 Bucket as it stores your application and settings as a bundle in that bucket and executes deployments. That bucket is required till the time you run/deploy your application using AWS EB. Please be vary of deleting these buckets as this may cause your deployments/applications to crash. Although, you may remove older objects (which may not be in use).

Take a look at this link for a detailed information on how EB uses S3 buckets for deployments https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.S3.html